# serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port

Tags: python-2.7, pyserial

I tried to communicate Python and Arduino with pyserial  on Win8
but it had error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Fon\Desktop\x.py", line 7, in <module>
    ser.open()                      # open serial port
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 66, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %r: %r" % (self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM4': WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot     find the file specified.')
```

this is my code

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = 3               # serial port
ser.baudrate = 115200           # set baudrate 115200
ser.timeout = 60                # timeout 60 second
ser.open()                      # open serial port

while True:
    ser.write('l')              # send '1' to port to get light
    light = ser.read(4) 
    print "light", light
```

in this code I tried to open port 'COM4', I already check this port is available and I already tried another port but it not worked any port. 
Am I using wrong port? or something? ;(

Comment: Does the port even exist? Maybe there is something already connected to it. If you ran the program before and the serial port didn't close correctly that old program may still be connected to it. If it doesn't exist then you will have to use a program to create a virtual serial port.

Comment: @JustinEngel execute me, how to check the port is exist? or how to create a virtual serial port?

Comment: If you are on windows the Device Manager has a ports section which will tell you what COM ports are on the computer. If you want to create a virtual serial port then there is an application called virtual serial port emulator http://www.eterlogic.com/Downloads.html

Comment: @JustinEngel Do i need to use the same port in python and arduino(COM1)? it can't communicated with each other.

Comment: If you are trying to talk to arduino on COM1 then you need python to connect to COM1. My guess is that something else is connected to the same serial port COM1. It could be the application you use to program your arduino or it could be a past program that didn't close correctly. You can try looking in your task manager for python.exe that is still running or try to safely disconnect your arduino and reconnect it. Other than that I'm not sure how to close a serial port connection that wasn't cleaned up properly. Make sure your python code has ser.close()